# Apply a sequence of different SKActions to different SKNodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to create a sequence of SKActions, each of which is for a different SKSpriteNode. I want to fade my `layer` node, remove it from the parent, wait for 3 seconds, then start a `move` SKAction for my `snake` node. Here's some code:

```
func startGame() {
    layer.run(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0, duration: 1),
        SKAction.removeFromParent(),
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1),
    ]))
    //Here move the snake node
}
```

The problem is, if I add `snake.run(SKAction.move(...))` at the place of the comment, it gets executed at the same time with `layer.run(...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run a block of code or function as an action (because in Swift closures are also function types), so you can add `SKAction.runBlock(moveSnake)` as the last `SKAction` on the array of actions run in `layer`.

Then in `func moveSnake() {}` you can run your actions to move the snake.